# Computer gets slow after some time. Sound starts to stutter

Tags: sound

I'm having a problem with my computer.

After some time using the PC, the sound starts to stutter whenever i watch a video on the browser or in VLC.

It just happen without any reason. I could be browsing the internet and everything is fine, then i leave the computer and when i come back the sound is jerky.

I've tried to check if there was something abnormal on system monitor, but everything seems fine. No high processor or memory usage. No process using to much memory. Nothing.

The only thing that seems to fix it is a restart. Not even a log out will do it.

What do you guys think i could to to diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I also got same error with VLC. I simply change my Player to KMPlayer.

Its working fine with my lap.

You Can [download](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/kmplayer/) on here or

```
sudo apt-get install kmplayer
```

As well as you can check VLC Player Bugs on [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bugs) , [askubuntu.com Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457966/vlc-crashes-on-xubuntu-14-04) and [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2191148)

Comment: No worries, it is good to encourage terminal usage ;) As a new user, you may be interested in http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer to help maximize the rep you receive from answers

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this also happens when I’m watching a video in Firefox.

Comment: update your drivers `sudo apt-get update` run this in terminal

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Ubuntu was up to date using the software updater. I just tried the some thing on terminal but i think it didn't installed nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with my browser (chrome). I have to use it without gpu sandbox to be more smooth when whatching video.

> google-chrome-stable --no-gpu-sandbox

This is not perfect but it's better than nothing. Video are still smooth on firefox by the way.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately is not a problem with a browser. It's a problem with the sound globally.